# How JUnit starts

Tags: java, junit

I'm figuring out how JUnit works. I can't understand how it runs itself, I understand that the `surefire` plugin interacts with JUnit, but I don't understand how JUnit itself runs. I'm trying to understand the debug output, and came across the `getRunner` method, but I can't get down to it, I can't understand what kind of package `com.intellij.rt.junit` is. Can you help me.

[image]

Comment: ok so  you got the runner, now follow the stream to see what is happening with it.

Comment: @Antoniossss , Hi, I mean, I want to understand how this runner is created

Comment: `com.intellij.rt.junit` is a package of IntelliJ for its built-in runner for JUnit tests. Is that the answer you're looking for, and if not, what is your question?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel ,  Hi, partially-yes. My task was to find out how JUnit starts, because I know that Java applications do not start without main(String []) and for me there is a mystery why JUnit starts and where it starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`com.intellij.rt.junit` is a package of IntelliJ for its built-in runner for JUnit tests, just like Surefire is the runner when tests are run from Maven.

JUnit itself also contains a basic commandline runner. For JUnit 5, see [Console Launcher](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-console-launcher), for JUnit 4, see [Test runners](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Test-runners). These are probably - but I didn't check it - easier to understand than the internals of the runners of Surefire or IntelliJ.